# Converting JSON to CSV using json2csv.py

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I did some online research and I found a script to convert JSON files to CSV file which I downloaded and stored on my local filesystem as `json2csv.py`. The tutorial says I have to execute this:

```
python.exe json2csv.py [input_file] [output_file]
```

Where do I need to store `json2csv.py` and what is the format of [input_file]? I tried typing this is in Python Shell(IDLE):

```
python.exe C:\json2csv.py [c:\inputfile.json] [c:\output.csv]
```

But I'm getting syntax error. I'm a newbie and really need help.

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: can you please post the code of this json2csv.py or the link to the tutorial? since the error that you're getting doesnt seem to be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the script (`json2csv.py`) and your input file (`inputfile.json`) are in the root of `C:` and that you wish to create the output in the same directory, you need to execute this from the command-line (Start > Run... > `cmd`<kbd>Return</kbd>) (and not from IDLE).

```
python.exe C:\json2csv.py c:\inputfile.json c:\output.csv
```